# Conversion in CET +01:00

Tags: oracle

In oracle I am trying to convert the below datetime to `CET`, but it not returning correctly. What's wrong with this?

```
2018-03-16T14:00:00+01:00
```

Query:

```
select cast(TO_timestamp_TZ('2018-03-16T14:00:00+01:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss tzr') as date) from dual;
```

Actual Output:

```
2018-03-16T14:00:00Z
```

Expected Output:

```
2018-03-16T15:00:00Z
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: The +01:00 indicates that the time zone is 1 hour ahead of UTC. It will not add one hour to your date.

Comment: But that meant we need to add 1 hour to convert to the local time right?

Comment: @ArtBajji, If so, what is the proper way to add it?

Comment: That is not possible. `+01:00` means **always** 1 hour ahead UTC, whereas `CET` can be 1 hour or 2 hours ahead UTC, depending on daylight times.

Comment: Thanks, so here what is the proper date to insert in  database? do we need to add +1:00 to the hour before inserting?

Comment: 14:00 +01:00 already means 2 PM CET. Why do you want to view it as 15:00 or 3 PM?

Comment: ohh if it is already CET, is the right time? I thought I need to add +1:00 to convert to CET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one?

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 12:00:00 +01:00' AT TIME ZONE 'CET', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss tzr'), 
    to_char(TIMESTAMP '2018-08-01 12:00:00 +01:00' AT TIME ZONE 'CET', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss tzr')
FROM dual;
```